# Magento 2 : Programmatically Create Customer and Then Login

Tags: magento2, customer, login

I am trying to create customer and then login programmatically. Below is my code :

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$params = $_SERVER;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$websiteId = $storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();

$firstName = 'Test';
$lastName = 'Test';
$email = 'test@example.com';
$password = 'Test@123';

$address = array(
    'customer_address_id' => '',
    'prefix' => '',
    'firstname' => $firstName,
    'middlename' => '',
    'lastname' => $lastName,
    'suffix' => '',
    'company' => '', 
    'street' => array(
        '0' => 'Customer Address 1', // this is mandatory
        '1' => 'Customer Address 2' // this is optional
    ),
    'city' => 'New York',
    'country_id' => 'US', // two letters country code
    'region' => 'New York', // can be empty '' if no region
    'region_id' => '43', // can be empty '' if no region_id
    'postcode' => '10450',
    'telephone' => '123-456-7890',
    'fax' => '',
    'save_in_address_book' => 1
);

$customerFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory')->create();

/**
 * check whether the email address is already registered or not
 */
$customer = $customerFactory->setWebsiteId($websiteId)->loadByEmail($email);

/** 
 * if email address already registered, return the error message
 * else, create new customer account
 */
if ($customer->getId()) {
    echo 'Customer with email '.$email.' is already registered.';  
} else {
    try {
        $customer = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory')->create();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
        $customer->setEmail($email);
        $customer->setFirstname($firstName);
        $customer->setLastname($lastName);
        $customer->setPassword($password);

        // save customer
        $customer->save();

        $customer->setConfirmation(null);
        $customer->save();

        $customAddress = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory')->create();
        $customAddress->setData($address)
                      ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
                      ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
                      ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
                      ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');

        // save customer address
        $customAddress->save();

        // Create customer session
        $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        $customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);

        echo 'Customer with email '.$email.' is successfully created.';

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Above code create customer successfully as I can find them in database but they are not visible in admin customer grid. Also, after creating customer I am trying to login programmatically but no success. Please help.

Comment: Any error in log file when above script executed?

Comment: No error in log files. I can log in from login page but it is not visible in admin customer's grid.

Comment: Try to run indexing one, then check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution :

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$params = $_SERVER;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$websiteId = $storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();

$firstName = 'Test';
$lastName = 'Test';
$email = 'aabb@example.com';
$password = 'Test@123';

$address = array(
    'customer_address_id' => '',
    'prefix' => '',
    'firstname' => $firstName,
    'middlename' => '',
    'lastname' => $lastName,
    'suffix' => '',
    'company' => '', 
    'street' => array(
        '0' => 'Customer Address 1', // this is mandatory
        '1' => 'Customer Address 2' // this is optional
    ),
    'city' => 'New York',
    'country_id' => 'US', // two letters country code
    'region' => 'New York', // can be empty '' if no region
    'region_id' => '43', // can be empty '' if no region_id
    'postcode' => '10450',
    'telephone' => '123-456-7890',
    'fax' => '',
    'save_in_address_book' => 1
);

$customerFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory')->create();

/**
 * check whether the email address is already registered or not
 */
$customer = $customerFactory->setWebsiteId($websiteId)->loadByEmail($email);

/** 
 * if email address already registered, return the error message
 * else, create new customer account
 */
if ($customer->getId()) {
    echo 'Customer with email '.$email.' is already registered.';  
} else {
    try {
        $customer = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory')->create();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
        $customer->setEmail($email);
        $customer->setFirstname($firstName);
        $customer->setLastname($lastName);
        $customer->setPassword($password);

        // save customer
        $customer->save();

        $customer->setConfirmation(null);
        $customer->save();

        $customAddress = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory')->create();
        $customAddress->setData($address)
                      ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
                      ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
                      ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
                      ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');

        // save customer address
        $customAddress->save();

        //reindex customer grid index
        $indexerFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory');
        $indexerId = 'customer_grid';
        $indexer = $indexerFactory->create();
        $indexer->load($indexerId);
        $indexer->reindexAll();

        // Create customer session
        $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        $customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);

        echo 'Customer with email '.$email.' is successfully created.';

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The customer probablu isn't visible in the admin customer grid because that get's cached. I also had that problem.

You can log in the customer like this:

```
public function loginNewCustomer($customer){
        if (!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            try {
                $this->customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                // Customer can't log in, this might be because the account needs to be confirmed.
            }
        }
    }
```

If you don't have the customer object yet at that location you can get $customer like this:

```
$customer = $this->_customer->loadByEmail("test@m2s.com"); 
$this->customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this using modern Magento 2 interfaces is as follows. Note I use the object manager directly, but best to use dependency injection. This will avoid deprecated function warnings:

```
    /**  @var CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerFactory */
    $customerFactory = $this->_bootstrap->getObjectManager()->get("\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory");

    $customer = $customerFactory->create();
    $customer->setWebsiteId(\ElectricLabs\MagentoHelpers::getCurrentStoreId());

    $customer->setEmail($emailAddress);
    $customer->setFirstname($firstName);
    $customer->setLastname($lastName);

    /**  @var CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository */
    $customerRepository = $this->_bootstrap->getObjectManager()->get("\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface");

    /**  @var Encryptor $encryptor */
    $encryptor = $this->_bootstrap->getObjectManager()->get("\Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor");
    $passwordHash = $encryptor->getHash($password, true);
    $customer = $customerRepository->save($customer, $passwordHash);

    // Login the new customer
    /**  @var SessionFactory $customerSessionFactory */
    $customerSessionFactory = $this->_bootstrap->getObjectManager()->get('Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory');
    $session = $customerSessionFactory->create();
    $session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);

    // Send new account email
    /**  @var EmailNotification $emailNotification */
    $emailNotification = $this->_bootstrap->getObjectManager()->get("\Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification");
    $emailNotification->newAccount($customer);
```